# How to apply lookup transformation column wise multiple times

Tags: ssis

I need to compare 2 data sets - excel and DB. While comparing need to check 4 fields say, A, B C & D columns from both the data sets. The output should tell which field is not matching like Mismatch A, Mismatch B etc. How can we implement this in SSIS? 
I tried implementing using lookup transformations multiple times. 1st time for column A and non matching records with Mismatch A and send matching records to 2nd lookup for column A & column B comparison. No match output from 2nd lookup as Mismatch B like this..
But this is not working after 1st lookup.

Comment: To restate: You have data from sources A and B. You will match based on a key. You would then like to do a column to column comparison to find differences?

Comment: Yes, I need to find those records where all those 4 columns doesn't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got solved !!! :) The issue was I was using output of 1st lookup in 2nd lookup as input instead of using the original input. Now am getting desired result.

Comment: Hi, I have column A,B and C. I want to use lookup transformation for A and B together. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Use a merge join transformation.  You would sort both inputs on the join key.  Once merged, use a derived column component to evaluate the columns.  i.e.

```
ExcelColumnA == dbColumnA ? "" : ("excel: + "ExcelColumnA + "; db: " + dbColumnA )
```

Name each column as mismatchA, etc.

Comment: I'm so happy you're answering on the SSIS tag ;)